# how to make a application open and close through a java program

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
run.exec("calc");//for opening calculator 
}
}
```

This opens the program but I am not able to close it.

How can I close the program I have opened?

I tried `destroy()` method too but dint work to destroy the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start it with:

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = run.exec("calc");
```

Note that you keep a reference to the started process in a variable of type `Process`.
Later you can stop it by calling `destroy()` on that `Process`:

```
process.destroy();
```